# How to compare Did received local notification value to Main view controller table view data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have received new data by didReceiveLocalNotification method and passing the data to main view controller. I want to compare notification data to tableview row cell data both are same or not. if same mean i need to change that particular tableview row cell color. All my code created by programmatically.

Here below I have posted my sample code :

in MainViewController.m
in viewDidLoad

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notifMainController:) name:@"notifMainController" object:nil];

-(void)notifMainController:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSLog(@"LOCAL NOTIFICATION RECEIVED DATA :%@",notif.object);
}
```

I need to compare `notif.object` value to tableview row cell data values using objective C...

Below I have posted how to load data into the tableview :

```
NSMutableArray *tableDatas;


    tableDatas value below :

    STORAGE : (
         {

        date = "2014-11-14";
        Country = USA;
     })



   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


           // Declaration :

           NSString * names = @"Country";

           NSDictionary *tabledataDictionary = [tableDatas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

           NSMutableString *Detail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tabledataDictionary objectForKey:names]];

           // Show the table title :
           cell.textLabel.text = Detail;



    }
```

Comment: Isn't  tableview row cell data comming from an NSArray/NSMutableArray/NSDictionary? you can edit it there, then reload the cell using it's indexPath

Comment: yes..I need to comapre with NSMutableArray value and change the color for few min...please post some sample code.

Comment: Show me what you get from NSNotification, because how can you compare the NSMutableArray's specified object with the notification without the searching key ?

Comment: Above posted code via I have received USA value...In tableview NSMutableArray already showing USA,CA,LA,....those kind of data's.now I need to comapre received USA value with tableview NSMutableArray value if both are same mean I need to change the tableview cell color.

Comment: Debanjan please help me....

Comment: I don't know your array structure, I just made one up, I hope this might help you, http://pastebin.com/1SNPYV6C

Comment: @Mano can you please tell what data you get in `NSMutableArray` ? update your question with `NSMutableArray` response.

Comment: I have edited @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani...Plz check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that store your notification string to global `NSString` and use `isEqualToString` to compare NSString.

in **.h**

```
NSString *strNotification;
```

in **.m**

```
-(void)notifMainController:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    strNotification = notif.object;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       // Declaration :
       NSDictionary *tabledataDictionary = [tableDatas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       NSString *detail = [tabledataDictionary objectForKey:@"Country"]];

       if([detail isEqualToString:strNotification])
        {
          // do what you want.
          cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        else
        {
          cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
       // Show the table title :
       cell.textLabel.text = detail;
}
```

Comment: But I cannt remove the color after clicking and back the same view..shown same color...

Comment: @Mano on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` make string is blank like `strNotification = @""`.